# Is there a Fire Emblem Chronology?

Tags: fire-emblem-series

Had a discussion with my brother and we ended up talking about if Ike, from Path of Radiance and Radiant Dawn, is the patriarch of most of the other main characters in Fire Emblem.

I found a discussion on GameFAQs where the general consensus is that there's only three games that aren't really connected, Sword of Fire, Binding Blade, and Sacred Stones.

The problem is that they couldn't seem to figure out if 9/10 (Path of Radiance and Radiant Dawn) come before 4's first half, or after the chain 4 starts but before 13 (Awakening).

Does anyone have any definitive answers on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of the Fire Emblem games exist in a [single timeline](http://fireemblemwiki.org/Timeline_of_Archanea,_Valentia_and_Jugdral), the earliest being [*Genealogy of the Holy War*](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Fire_Emblem:_Genealogy_of_the_Holy_War), and the most recent being [*Awakening*](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Fire_Emblem:_Awakening).

Three [other timelines](http://fireemblemwiki.org/Timeline) also exist, but are not directly tied to the aforementioned timeline:

- The Elibe timeline consists of *[Blazing Sword](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Fire_Emblem:_Blazing_Sword)* and *[The Binding Blade](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Fire_Emblem:_The_Binding_Blade)*.
- The Magvel timeline consists solely of *[The Sacred Stones](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Fire_Emblem:_The_Sacred_Stones)*.
- The Tellius timeline consists of *[Path of Radiance](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Fire_Emblem:_Path_of_Radiance)* and *[Radiant Dawn](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Fire_Emblem:_Radiant_Dawn)*.

*Awakening* provides tie-ins to these timelines through the use of other "realms", although it is unclear whether the timelines run parallel or not. It also includes hints as to how the timelines may coincide:

- In the DLC, [Lyn](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Lyn) claims that [Robin](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Avatar_(Awakening)) is [the tactician](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Tactician_(Blazing_Sword)) from Blazing Sword.
- [Ike](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Ike)'s descendant, [Priam](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Priam), can be recruited in one of the bonus chapters.
- Time travel and parallel realities do occur, so timelines may not be linear.

As for whether Ike is a direct ancestor to the main characters of the other Fire Emblem games, it seems highly unlikely. Priam's status as Ike's descendent and [Chrom](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Chrom)'s status as [Marth](http://fireemblemwiki.org/wiki/Marth)'s descendant both appear to be well-known and bear no overlap. Given that it is unknown when the Tellius timeline occurs in relation to the primary timeline, it is not impossible that Ike is a direct ancestor to the lords of the other games, but all evidence points away from this being the case.

Comment: A bit of research into Priam, for the sake of boredom mostly, I discovered that Ike's deeds are very real in Awakening, if less important to Chrom's area of the world than Marth's.

This lends credence to the idea that Ike is not Marth's ancestor, though it still doesn't make it impossible, and that Path of Radiance and Radiant Dawn, both happened in the main timeline somewhere, possibly/probably on a different continent.

Comment: @Selonianth All of the other continents sank in the Great Flood in Path of Radiance and Radiant Dawn.